# mock function with variable number of aguments using NSubstitute

Tags: c#, mocking, nsubstitute

I have an interface with the following method:

```
bool ProcessActions(int actionTypeId, out List<int> ints, params object[] actionParameters);
```

Now how can mock this method to return a value using NSubstitute? Here is what I've tried:

```
    this.actionOperationsMock.ProcessActions(Arg.Any<int>(), out List<int> _, Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<int>(), Arg.Any<DateTime>(), Arg.Any<DateTime>(), Arg.Any<string>()).Returns(
        x =>
            {
                x[1] = null;
                return true;
            });
```

I've tried to mock it only with the first two parameters, but in my tests, this method is returning false.

Comment: Did you try to use `Arg.Any<object[]>()`? Your `actionParams` are of type `object[]`, so I guess this should do it. Or are you specifically asking for this combination of types?

Comment: Why won't you use ReturnsForAnyArgs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd advise to use ReturnsForAnyArgs since you are going to mock each one of parameters and params object[] don't have to be mocked in that case since params allow 0 arguments.

```
mock.ProcessActions(Arg.Any<int>(), out Arg.Any<List<int>>()).ReturnsForAnyArgs(
            x =>
            {
                x[1] = null;
                return true;
            });

        var res = mock.ProcessActions(1, out var list, 1, 1, 1 , DateTime.Now, DateTime.Now.AddHours(2), "");
```